# Return additional Entity not mapped, on an odata controller

Tags: .net-core, odata

I am in need of returning a list of entities (Proposals) from an odata controller, but it needs to also return another Property entity together (Summary) with it that is populated from the Summarize method. This other entity is not persisted nor does existing in the dbcontext (builder.Ignore(p => p.Summary)).

The issue is that it can't be a complextype for my use, so I tried to add it as a EntitySet on the buiilder and Automatic expand on the parent (as I can't add it to the query the expand), but then every time I try to query it, the following exception raises.

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Cannot serialize a null 'ResourceSet'.
at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext) [...]
```

I wonder if this happens because of the entity not existing to the context.

So is there a way to make this work? to not have this other entity persisted but return it together with the odata query for its parent?

Results:

```
{"@odata.context":"http://localhost:57450/OData/$metadata#Proposal","value":[{"ProposalID":"e91cacfc-f345-4617-bd54-b1f440e4fd65","CustomerNumber":null,"Description":"","ServiceType":"LeaseReturn","Currency":null,"PartnerName":null,"QuoteDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00-02:00","CreatedOn":"2018-08-06T16:27:52.8169404-03:00","CreatedBy":"Admin","UpdatedOn":null,"UpdatedBy":null,"ProposalServiceFees":[]},{"ProposalID":"28ddfea6-2ac9-4898-b72f-d5e284d5072f","CustomerNumber":"2","Description":"a","ServiceType":"ResaleAndRecycle","Currency":null,"PartnerName":null,"QuoteDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00-02:00","CreatedOn":"2018-08-15T15:11:07.531755-03:00","CreatedBy":"Admin","UpdatedOn":null,"UpdatedBy":null,"ProposalServiceFees":[]}]}
```

Expected:

```
{"@odata.context":"http://localhost:57450/OData/$metadata#Proposal","value":[{"ProposalID":"e91cacfc-f345-4617-bd54-b1f440e4fd65","CustomerNumber":null,"Description":"","ServiceType":"LeaseReturn","Currency":null,"PartnerName":null,"QuoteDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00-02:00","CreatedOn":"2018-08-06T16:27:52.8169404-03:00","CreatedBy":"Admin","UpdatedOn":null,"UpdatedBy":null,"Summary":{"SummaryId":"e91cacfc-f345-4617-bd54-b1f440e4fd65","Items":[{"Type":"workstation","Price":0.00}],"Fees":[]},"ProposalServiceFees":[]},{"ProposalID":"28ddfea6-2ac9-4898-b72f-d5e284d5072f","CustomerNumber":"2","Description":"a","ServiceType":"ResaleAndRecycle","Currency":null,"PartnerName":null,"QuoteDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00-02:00","CreatedOn":"2018-08-15T15:11:07.531755-03:00","CreatedBy":"Admin","UpdatedOn":null,"UpdatedBy":null,"Summary":{"SummaryId":"28ddfea6-2ac9-4898-b72f-d5e284d5072f","Items":[{"Type":"strings","Price":0.00}],"Fees":[]},"ProposalServiceFees":[]}]}
```

---

Entities:

```
public class Proposal : EntityBase {
    public Guid ProposalID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ServiceType { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public Summary Summary { get; set; }
    public string PartnerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime QuoteDate { get; set; }
 [...]
    public void Summarize()
        => Summary = new Summary(Assets, ProposalServiceFees.Select(f=>f.ServiceFee), ProposalID);
 }

 public class Summary
 {
    public Guid SummaryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SummaryItem> Items { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<SummaryItem> Fees { get; private set; }

    internal Summary(IEnumerable<Asset> assets, IEnumerable<ServiceFee> fees, Guid id)
    {
        SummaryId = id;  //dummy for test

        Items = assets
            .GroupBy(asset => asset.ProductType, GroupIntoSummaryItem)
            .ToList();

        Fees = fees
            .Select(f=> FeeToSummaryItem(f.ApplyServiceFee(assets.Count())))
            .ToList();
    }
    [...]
}
```

Controller:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute()]
    public IQueryable<Proposal.Domain.Entities.Proposal> Get(ODataQueryOptions opts)
    {
        opts.Validate(settings);

        IQueryable results = opts.ApplyTo(_context.Proposal.Include(x => x.Assets)).AsQueryable();

        var values = (results as IQueryable<Proposal.Domain.Entities.Proposal>)?.ToList();

        values?.ForEach(x => x.Summarize());

        return values?.AsQueryable();
    }
```

OdataConventionModelBuilder:

```
        EntitySet<Summary>(nameof(Summary))
            .EntityType
            .HasKey(p => p.SummaryId)
            .Filter()
            .Count()
            .Expand()
            .OrderBy()
            .Page()
            .Select();

        EntitySet<Domain.Entities.Proposal>(nameof(Domain.Entities.Proposal))
            .EntityType
            .HasKey(p => p.ProposalID)
            .Expand(SelectExpandType.Automatic, nameof(Summary))
            .Filter()
            .Count()
            .Expand()
            .OrderBy()
            .Page()
            .Select();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to your model structure not matching your DB structure. This happens quite often when you cut/paste and forget to rename an entity.